# How to execute Celery periodic tasks on Django project

Tags: django, redis, celery

Seems that it's very easy to implement periodic tasks with Celery, just do something like:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week="mon"))
def every_monday_morning():
    print("This is run every Monday morning at 7:30")
```

Some tutorials suggest to put these tasks on a file called "tasks.py", but after doing that now what?. How I tell django or celery to "activate" or "run" these tasks?.

Also, those kind of tasks relays only on Celery or there's the need to use Celery + Redis (I already have configured it), but Redis it's never mentiones on tutorials or documentation for periodic tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [celery documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.0-archived/getting-started/periodic-tasks.html#starting-celerybeat) says:

> If you want to use periodic tasks you need to start the `celerybeat` service. You have to make sure only one instance of this server is running at any time, or else you will end up with multiple executions of the same task.

Go ahead and read the entire page of documentation, I think it directly answers your question. I do not believe Redis is going to help you run periodic tasks, however your server will need to run `celerybeat`.